# How can Rails' REST implementation be said to be REST at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

So, I'm learning Ruby on Rails. I get the fundamentals of the RESTful approach to application architecture, but I haven't yet built a RESTful application completely.

In a traditional web application, idempotent requests (which don't change any state) are made via HTTP's `GET` method and all non-idempotent requests are typically made via the `POST` method. For the application to distinguish between the different actions a `POST` request might be triggering, there's usually a hidden field in the form that gets included with the `POST` request, like `action=delete` or `action=add_to_foo_file`. This is a fairly simple architecture and is pretty common today, but the REST approach steers us away from this and suggests that this "let's POST everything!" design is considered harmful.

Instead, a RESTful architecture has us manipulating resources via the URIs which uniquely identify them (nouns) and the HTTP request methods (verbs), instead of determining what action to take based on a separate field in the request:

```
GET    => show the resource
PUT    => update the resource
POST   => create a new resource
DELETE => destroy the resource
```

So now we come to Ruby on Rails. In Rails, `PUT` and `DELETE` are implemented by JavaScript, which changes your links into forms with a hidden field called `_method`. The form is received from the browser via `POST`, and then Rails looks for this field and decides whether to route the request to the `PUT` or `DELETE` methods of the controller.

Wait, what? That sounds suspiciously like -- even exactly like -- the behavior of a traditional web application, which receives all state-changing requests via `POST` and inspects specific fields to decide whether to destroy or modify a record.

**So how can Rails' approach be said to be RESTful *at all*, since under the hood, it is just a re-implementation of the "let's POST everything" approach which REST specifically attempts to move away from?**

And further, **doesn't this approach prevent my Rails app from ever degrading gracefully for people with JS turned off in the browser?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes a system RESTful or not isn't so much the verb it uses, but the fact the interactions are driven by the hypermedia (in this case, this includes code-on-demand JavaScript).

The GET/PUT/POST/DELETE mapping you're quoting works fine for CRUD operations, but isn't necessarily appropriate for everything (and isn't necessarily supported by all browsers). This is a reasonable rule of thumb to design a RESTful system, but it's neither sufficient nor necessary. (It's in the same category of ideas as what people insist on when they want "RESTful" URIs: there's no such thing.)

Part of this comes under influence of books like [RESTful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260). It's a good book, but it came out at a time where WS-*/SOAP was predominant, and where everything was tunnelled through POST. A reaction to SOAP was to make people aware that there were other HTTP verbs they could use.

For REST, what really matters in particular is to respect the notions behind the URI concept, the semantics of each HTTP verb (no side-effects, idempotent requests, ..., where appropriate and if you're using HTTP) and the HATEOS principle. It's an architectural style, don't stress too much about what POST/PUT/DELETE the JavaScript does underneath.

You should certainly read these:

- [*REST APIs must be hypertext-driven*](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)
- [*It is okay to use POST*](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

**EDIT:** (Following comments)

> What I should have said was this: If most frameworks turn `DELETE`
>   `http://server.tld/resource/1` into `POST`
>   `http://server.tld/resource/1?_method=DELETE`, then what's the advantage
>   of that approach over just using `POST`
>   `http://server.tld/resource/1?my_method=delete` in the first place?

- It makes the overall goal a little bit cleaner/clearer, in terms of API design. REST frameworks can ultimately only be as RESTful as one uses them, since REST is an architectural style, not a protocol or an implementation.
- In addition, strictly speaking, the URI includes the query component, so `http://server.tld/resource/1` and `http://server.tld/resource/1?my_method=DELETE` could identify different resources in principle (although that wouldn't be a good design choice).
- It's good for the framework to be able to expose `DELETE`/`PUT` as such directly, but have a fallback solution via `POST` for the clients that don't support it.

  The reason for this is that clients that do support `DELETE`/`PUT` will be able to make use of them, and make assumptions about their usage. It's not so much of a problem for the client to treat a request as non-idempotent even if it was idempotent in principle as the opposite. If the client thinks it can send at most 1 request (non-idempotent) when it could have sent N+1 of the requests, this doesn't cause major problems; if the client thinks it can send N+1 times the same request for something that shouldn't be idempotent, this can cause quite a lot of problems. Emulating `PUT` through `POST` is OK, you're just not making the most of `PUT`, emulating `POST` through `PUT` would be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Rails of course supports the proper HTTP verbs (and soon even PATCH). The only problem is: the browsers don't as they only support GET and POST. To circumvent this limitation, Rails offers the additional facility to "override" the actual HTTP verb with a `_method` parameter which is what you described.

The main and proper way to use the API is through actual HTTP verbs instead. With a capable client, you can and are encouraged to do this.

As for your second question regarding graceful degradation, it is up to you, the developer, to make sure your app works in all circumstances important to you. If you want your app to work without JavaScript, you can always resort to create actual HTML forms and a submit button. The generated Javascript links are just another way if you really want to have a link which creates a PUT. Again, this is nothing which Rails thought would be great but is a way to circumvent restrictions imposed by all current browser implementations.

Comment: Plus, JavaScript isn't required just to add a _method parameter. You can use a hidden form field.

Comment: @RobDavis: In fact, when parsing the `:method` parameter to the Rails form helper, it will create this exact hidden field to the form. This is the recommended implementation strategy

Answer (score 1):

The problem with PUT and DELETE requests is the fact that HTML forms don't support it. The way most frameworks handle that is by tunneling them through a POST request.

You can still do "curl -X DELETE http://example.com/posts/1", which would still work.

Although, there are a lot of misapprehensions about Rails and Rest. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS and http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2010/12/rails-misapprehensions-rest-is-more-than-get-post-put-and-delete/

Comment: Yes, I understand that browsers don't handle `PUT` or `DELETE` requests. But if "most frameworks" tunnel these through a `POST` request, it's still a `POST` request, and therefore not RESTful, right? I'm having a hard time seeing how tunneling a `DELETE` through a `POST` request is BETTER than just using a `POST` request in the first place.

Comment: @Jazz, you can still do "curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/posts/1
" and it would work. It is RESTful, the "_method" is used for HTML.

Comment: "*But if "most frameworks" tunnel these through a POST request, it's still a POST request, and therefore not RESTful, right?*": you should really read '*It is okay to use POST*'.

Comment: @Bruno Just went and read it (thanks for the link). What I should have said was this: If most frameworks turn `DELETE http://server.tld/resource/1` into `POST http://server.tld/resource/1?_method=DELETE`, then what's the advantage of that approach over just using `POST http://server.tld/resource/1?my_method=delete` in the first place?